# Include javascript from assembly in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, embedded-resource

Is there any way that I could include a javascript file that is an embedded resource of an assembly in my Views for MVC 3?

I have tried to create an Action that gets the embedded resource from the assembly and then returns a FileStreamResult like so...

```
 public FileStreamResult Scripts()
 {
    System.Reflection.Assembly myassembly;
    myassembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    System.IO.Stream file =
       myassembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Testing.testscript.js");
    return File(file, "application/x-javascript");
 }
```

Then in my master view:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    @Html.RenderAction("Scripts")

  </script>
```

This doesn't seem too work.

I would rather just be able to get the embedded resource as a link and then use that as my src value for the script. So something like:

```
<script src="@Html.GetEmbeddedResourceAsLink("Testing.testscript.js")"/>
```

Anyone know how?

Comment: `This doesn't seem too work.` Why? What error are u getting?

Comment: Its embeddeding the script inline and the page does not render in IE because of a MIME error. I tried a "text/javascript", "application/x-javascript" and "javascript"... This does work in FF4, but I would rather the script not be inline anyway, but rather a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GetWebResourceUrl might be useful here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getwebresourceurl.aspx

The example code on that MSDN page is for WebForms but I think the following might work:

```
string rsname = "MyAssembly.my_script.js";

string url = ((Page)HttpContext.CurrentHandler)
    .ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), rsname);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is meant to be rendered on the server only, try returning `new ContentResult(jsContent)`.